# add to the height of div on program run html

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a datagrid that has some content. There is a expandable/Collapsable area above the content(picture 1)[image]. When i expand the  content, the datagrid element will create a scroll bar and show the data.
Picture 2[image]

If there is a way to dynamically update the max height with current height with current height + 30px, the issue may be solved. How is this possible

```
.panelGrid {
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Here is the div part of code

```
  <asp:Panel Style="font-size: 14px;" Visible='<%# Eval("Description").ToString() == "Discharges" %> ' runat="server">

                                                                <label class="collapsible" style="font-size: 10px;">Check List</label>

                                                                <div class="content text-left">

                                                                    <ul>
                                                                        <li>
                                                                            <a href="../Iframes/IFDC.aspx" target="_blank" runat="server" onclick="window.open('../Iframes/IFDC.aspx', 'InstitutionalFUllCheckListWindow','width=1680,height=1300, scrollbars=1,resizable=1'); return false;">Institutional – Pre Settlement Checklist</a>
                                                                        </li>
                                                                        <li><a href="../Iframes/DMARDFC.aspx" target="_blank" runat="server" onclick="window.open('../Iframes/DMARDFC.aspx', 'DischargeMortgageCheckListWindow', 'width=1680,height=1300, scrollbars=1,resizable=1'); return false;">Institutional – Post Settlement Checklist</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="../Iframes/FFDC.aspx" target="_blank" runat="server" onclick="window.open('../Iframes/FFDC.aspx', 'FundFUllCheckListWindow', 'width=1680,height=1300, scrollbars=1,resizable=1'); return false;">Private– Pre Settlement Checklist</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="../Iframes/PDC.aspx" target="_blank" runat="server" onclick="window.open('../Iframes/PDC.aspx', 'PartialDischargeCheckListWindow', 'width=1680,height=1300, scrollbars=1,resizable=1'); return false;">Partial – Pre Settlement Checklist</a></li>
                                                                    </ul>

                                                                </div>

                                                                <%--<a href="../Checklists/DischargeCheckList.aspx" target="_blank" runat="server" onclick="window.open('../Checklists/DischargeCheckList.aspx', 'DischargeCheckListWindow', 'width=1680,height=1050, scrollbars=1,resizable=1'); return false;">Discharge Checklist</a>&nbsp;<asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Images/cross.png" runat="server" ID="DischargeCheckListStatus" />--%>
                                                            </asp:Panel>
                                                        </asp:Panel>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding: 1px 10px 1px 20px; min-height: 30px">
                                                        <telerik:RadGrid ID="gridDocuments" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeader="True" OnItemCommand="gridDocuments_ItemCommand" AllowMultiRowSelection="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridDocuments_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that i came up with was to add a javascript to check when the class collapsible is clicked and see if it matches the name , then update the max height

```js
  <script>
        var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {

            coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                var content = this.nextElementSibling;
                if (content.style.maxHeight) {
                    content.style.maxHeight = null;
                } else {
                    content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
                }
                if (content.id == 'DischargeCheckList') {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("panelGrid")[19].style.maxHeight = (document.getElementsByClassName("panelGrid")[19].scrollHeight + document.getElementById("DischargeCheckList").scrollHeight) + "px";
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="panelGrid">
  <asp:Panel Style="font-size: 14px;" Visible='<%# Eval("Description").ToString() == "Discharges" %> ' runat="server">

    <label class="collapsible" style="font-size: 10px; height: 30px">Check List</label>

    <div class="content text-left" id="DischargeCheckList">

      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="../Iframes/IFDC.aspx" target="_blank" runat="server" onclick="window.open('../Iframes/IFDC.aspx', 'InstitutionalFUllCheckListWindow','width=1680,height=1300, scrollbars=1,resizable=1'); return false;">Institutional – Pre Settlement Checklist</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="../Iframes/DMARDFC.aspx" target="_blank" runat="server" onclick="window.open('../Iframes/DMARDFC.aspx', 'DischargeMortgageCheckListWindow', 'width=1680,height=1300, scrollbars=1,resizable=1'); return false;">Institutional – Post Settlement Checklist</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Iframes/FFDC.aspx" target="_blank" runat="server" onclick="window.open('../Iframes/FFDC.aspx', 'FundFUllCheckListWindow', 'width=1680,height=1300, scrollbars=1,resizable=1'); return false;">Private– Pre Settlement Checklist</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Iframes/PDC.aspx" target="_blank" runat="server" onclick="window.open('../Iframes/PDC.aspx', 'PartialDischargeCheckListWindow', 'width=1680,height=1300, scrollbars=1,resizable=1'); return false;">Partial – Pre Settlement Checklist</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>


  </asp:Panel>
</div>
```